# How to zoom image inside rectangle WPF

Tags: wpf, zooming

I am trying to zoom in and out image inside Rectangle control. But while doing so my entire Rectangle is getting zoomed in instead of just image inside that. for doing so I am using ScaleTransform and TranslateTranform on Rectangle. I should do the same on image instead of Rectangle but I dont know how? Could anyone please help me out.

XAML :

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="LiveViewWindow" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
            ClipToBounds="True" />
```

Code:

```
InteropBitmap m_LiveViewBitmapSource =Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection(
    section, width, height, PixelFormats.Bgr32, width*4, 0) as InteropBitmap;

ImageBrush m_BackgroundFrame = new ImageBrush(m_LiveViewBitmapSource);

RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(m_BackgroundFrame, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);

LiveViewWindow.Fill = m_BackgroundFrame;
```

n then for I am using Invalidate() property to render InteropBitmap to Rectangle.

Comment: What does "image inside rectangle" mean? Show your XAML please.

Comment: @Clemens: I have updated my question. I am thinking of applying all transforms to my InteropBitmap now before Invalidate(). But I don't know how to for it?? There is nothing on internet for reference. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.transform.aspx) property of the ImageBrush. Get more information in [Brush Transformation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970500.aspx).

Comment: The thing is I am processing live frame from camera. I am assigning Imagebrush only once. Whenever I get new frame I just call Invalidate() in a callback function. So I have to have to process InteropBitmap cause thats only available when I am doing Callback.